# Mamp: MySQL not starting

Tags: mysql, mamp

I am trying to get Mamp working.

But MySQL doesn't wants to start.
I think it has to do with that I don't have a `mysql.sock` file in `tmp/mysql`. I have already tried reinstalling Mamp but unfortunately that didn't work.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: My suggestion: get rid of MAMP and use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/): `brew install httpd mariadb php@5.6` then just `mysql.server start` **Do not `sudo` this command**

Comment: I forgot to say that I'm  using mac. Is this also possible for mac?

Comment: > From Homebrew website: *Homebrew The missing package manager for **macOS***

Comment: OK, thanks, I will try it.

Comment: `180525 18:25:34 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
. ERROR!`

Comment: I have fixed the error :). MySQL wasn't closed correctly.

Comment: OK, but I don't really know how this works. 1. How can I go to my webpage? 2. Where do I need to place the .html files? 3. (How) can I use PHPMyAdmin?